# Magento 2 How to send order email copy to custom email address with custom module when order placed?

Tags: magento2, checkout, module, orders, email

I have one module where i can set email address in back end. When order placed i want to send that order email copy to my custom email address which is set in backend.

I want to add an observer when order placed and send email copy to my custom email address.

how can i achieve this functionality with custom module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

May be this functionality already provided by the Magento 2

**Please Follow Below steps for that**

```
Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails -> Order -> Send Order Email Copy To
```

[image]

Comment: i want to send order copy with my custom module observer.